# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin :3.8.0:compile (default-compile)

Tags: spring-boot

I tried to download Maven  but I get this error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin :3.8.0:compile (default-compile)
```

I cannot find a solution

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------< com.example.demo:TSIRH2019-masterv2 >-----------------
[INFO] Building TSIRH2019-masterv2 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ TSIRH2019-masterv2 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ TSIRH2019-masterv2 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 52 source files to C:\Users\User\Desktop\SPRINGBOOTmarie\TSIRH2019-master\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/SPRINGBOOTmarie/TSIRH2019-master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/entity/Personnels.java:[24,38] package com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.ha does not exist
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.843 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-13T11:53:14+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project TSIRH2019-masterv2: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/SPRINGBOOTmarie/TSIRH2019-master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/entity/Personnels.java:[24,38] package com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.ha does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I think I need to add or delete something to my Pom.xml but I do not know what to edit. Here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <groupId>com.example.demo</groupId>
   <artifactId>TSIRH2019-masterv2</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <name>TSIRH2019-masterv2</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nulab-inc</groupId>
            <artifactId>zxcvbn</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
        </dependency>               
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>       
        <dependency>
         <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
          <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
           <version>2.9.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
             <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
             <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-compiler-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [${org.apache.maven.plugins.version},)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO is an English-language website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
   </dependency>
```